# In C#, What is the fastest way to search for elements in a list but do a "StartsWith()" search?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, trie, startswith

I have a list of strings:

```
 var list = new List<string>();
 list.Add("CAT");
 list.Add("DOG");

var listofItems = new List<string>();
 listofItems .Add("CATS ARE GOOD");
 listofItems .Add("DOGS ARE NICE");
 listofItems .Add("BIRD");
 listofItems .Add("CATAPULT");
 listofItems .Add("DOGGY");
```

and now i want a function like this:

```
 listofItems.Where(r=> list.Contains(r));
```

but instead of Contains, i want it to do a starts with check so 4 out of the 5 items would be returned (BIRD would NOT).

What is the fastest way to do that?

Comment: why not a trie tree or some other type of prefix tree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [StartsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) inside of an [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
listofItems.Where(item=>list.Any(startsWithWord=>item.StartsWith(startsWithWord)))
```

You can visualize this as a double `for` loop, with the second `for` breaking out as soon as it hits a `true` case

```
var filteredList = new List<String>();
foreach(var item in listOfItems)
{
    foreach(var startsWithWord in list)
    {
        if(item.StartsWith(startsWithWord))
        {
            filteredList.Add(item)
            break;
        }
    }
}
return filteredList;
```

Comment: lol thought it was just me seeing that(about your comment in the other answer) :)....+1

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way would be usage of another data structure, for example Trie. Basic C# implementation can be found here: https://github.com/kpol/trie

Answer (score 0):

This should get you what you need in a more simplified format:

```
 var result = listofItems.Select(n =>
 {
      bool res = list.Any(v => n.StartsWith(v));
      return res 
               ? n 
               : string.Empty;
 }).Where(b => !b.Equals(string.Empty));
```

Answer (score 0):

The Trie data structure is what you need. Take a look at this more mature library: [TrieNet](https://github.com/gmamaladze/trienet)

```
using Gma.DataStructures.StringSearch;

...

var trie = new SuffixTrie<int>(3);

trie.Add("hello", 1);
trie.Add("world", 2);
trie.Add("hell", 3);

var result = trie.Retrieve("hel");
```